# Where i can find the systemjs.config.js in angular 4 Application?

Tags: angular

I created the angular application via angular cli, I want to use the angular material in that application.

In the angular material document, they said to add some code in systemjs file.but I can't figure out where that file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular CLI no longer creates Angular boilerplates with systemJS config - it creates Angular with integrated Webpack.

Step 1-5 in the documentation [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) you install the dependencies through NPM packages, and then you import what you need. So for importing the style for example, add this line to your styles.css

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

In step 6, "Appendix: Configuring SystemJS", is only for older versions of Angular Projects still using SystemJS. As you use an up to date version, you dont need this step, and just need the steps wihtin 1-5

Comment: my angular CLI version is 1.5.0

Comment: I updated my post, I misunderstood your question at first.

Comment: No yar, I am speaking about Configuring SystemJS.

Comment: See the angular material website after 6th step.https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: In the 6th step, "Appendix: Configuring SystemJS", is only if you have an old version of the Angular Project still using SystemJS. As you use an up to date version, you dont need this step, and just need the steps wihtin 1-5.

Comment: please change the answer.Above comment is the correct answer.anyway thanks

Comment: but i think in some scenarios we still need it, as i am trying to use ckeditor (ng2-ckeditor) and its documentation is telling me to add configurations to SystemJS

Comment: If you need to use plugins that are only supported in the old Angular 2, then you need to make a project in Angular2 and get yourself stuck in that old version, because Angular moved out of using SystemJS and now only using Webpack. I recommend to use plugins that are following the development of Angular.